# Swift UITableView reloadData() UI behavior

Tags: swift, uitableview

We are loading data via REST call:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in
    //Update data store….
    self.tableView.reloadData()
})
task.resume()
```

The data in the grid is not shown however.  You have to click on the grid in the simulator - when you do this the data is shown.  What are we missing here to get the data to automatically load without any UI interaction?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `reloadData()` method must run in the main thread. `dataTaskWithRequest(_ request: NSURLRequest)` runs in a background thread:

```
let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{
        //Update data store….
        self.tableView.reloadData()
    })

})

task.resume()
```

Comment: Works thanks.   One thing - I put the updating of the data store outside/above the dispatch_async call.

Comment: @MarcusLeon No worries, only UI-tasks must run in the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

The completion handler gets called on a background thread. You must call `reloadData` on the main thread/queue.